# Find from what file is part of the text powershell .txt

Tags: powershell, filter

I have lets say 8 files named log1.txt, log2.txt, log3.txt ... saved in "C:\Users\krivosik\Desktop\Scripts\logs". I have filtered how many words "dog" and "cat" are in all these files. Now I need to know how many words "dog" and "cat" there are in each file.
For example I know there are 300 words "dog" and 250 words "cat" in all 8 files. I need to know that log1.txt includes 30 words "dog" and 20 words "cat", log2.txt includes 50 words "dog" and 10 words "cat".

I tried:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Select-String "dog" -List | Select Path
```

Comment: Can each word of interest appear only (at most) _once_ per line?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that each pattern (search string) only appears (at most) *once* per line, combine [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) with [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object):

```bash
Get-ChildItem -File C:\Users\krivosik\Desktop\Scripts\logs | 
  Select-String dog, cat |
  Group-Object Pattern, Path |
  ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject] @{
      Pattern = $_.Group[0].Pattern
      Count = $_.Group.Count
      Path = $_.Group[0].Path
    }
  }
```

Sample output:

```
Pattern Count Path
------- ----- ----
cat        20 C:\Users\krivosik\Desktop\Scripts\logs\log1.txt
dog         5 C:\Users\krivosik\Desktop\Scripts\logs\log2.txt
# ...
```